# Contacts didn't enter a running version while a previous version had "finishing" status in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a journey in Journey Builder that has a version with "finishing" status and then another version was activated. However, the day that the journey has to be launched, no contact entered neither the "finishing" version nor the "running" version. However, all previous versions have functioned well. Can someone explain why would my contacts not enter the journey? 
Is it because the two versions kinda coincides? "finishin vs running"?

Thank you,

Comment: What is your re-entry criteria set to?  What is the entry source and schedule?

Comment: When your journey had the re entry criteria „no reentry“ no contact that has been in version 1 will be allowed to enter version 2. the same happens when there is a Long wait period at the end of the first journey and you set the reentry to entry only after exiting. Another thing that can happen is that your filter criteria might have been to restricted. Maybe you have to take a closer look inside the activity tab of the journey and furthermore post more details about the journey configuration. We can only guess if you give to few details.

Answer (score 0):

Your contacts did not enter the journey because they were still in the finishing version of the journey. Unless you set the Journey Settings to “Re-entry Anytime” then they contacts won’t re-enter the journey.

- No re-entry means that contacts can enter the journey only once and can never enter the journey again.
- Re-entry only after exiting means that a contact must exit the journey before being allowed to enter again.
- Re-entry anytime allows a contact to enter the journey multiple times, and the same contact can be at different points of the journey simultaneously.

See re-entry settings here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_bp_journey_entry_control_best_practices.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null